# Difference in the values of atoi

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
char* input = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER) // buffer is defined to 100
int digit = atoi(input); // convert char into a digit
int digit_check = 0;
digit_check += digit % 10; // get last value of digit
```

When I run the input 1234567896 and similarly digit = 1234567896 and digit_check = 6.

However when I run the input 9999999998, digit = 1410065406 and therefore digit_check = 6 when it should be 8.

For the second example, why is there a difference between input and digit when it should be the same value?

Comment: You need to figure out the max value an int can store on your platform.

Comment: @nos Just learnt about it thank you.

Comment: sizeof(char) is 1 by definition. You can safely use "malloc(BUFFER)". In C you can also avoid casting the return value of malloc().

Comment: In addition to @Jack's remarks, if `BUFFER` (where `BUFFER_SIZE` would be a better name) is `#define`d to 100 (a compile-time constant), you can simplify your program by avoiding dynamic memory allocation altogether and just have a `char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`atoi` is limited to an int size (32 bits on most recent plateform).

If you want to handle large numbers, you can use `atol` or `scanf("%ld")`.

Don't forget to type your variable to `long int` (or `long`).

---

You could also just getting the very last character of your input (gathered as a string rather than as an int) and use `atoi` on it, so it would never overflow.

Comment: And the maximum value a signed 32 bit integer (using 2's complement) can hold is 2147483647.

Comment: @blue112 Thank you for the swift and easily understandable answer will mark as answered as soon as it lets me

Comment: @5gon12eder: Strictly speaking, properties of the positive subrange of signed integer types do not depend on the signed representation. I.e. "2's complement" has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @AnT True for 1's complement, 2's complement, sign-magnitude and symmetric biased representation.  In theory, you could define a weird number format where the positive range were different but I'm not sure whether the C standard would allow that and I'm pretty sure that no implementation uses it.

Answer (score 6):

Probably because 9999999998 is bigger then the maximum (signed) integer representation, so you get an overflow.

In fact this is the binary representation of 9999999998 and 1410065406:

```
10  01010100 00001011 11100011 11111110
    01010100 00001011 11100011 11111110
```

As you can see if you see 1410065406 is the 32ed bit value of 9999999998

Answer (score 1):

On many platforms size of `int` is limited by 4 bytes, that limits digit in `[-2 ** 31, 2**31 - 1]`.

Use `long` (or `long long`) with `strtol` (or `strtoll`) depending on platform you build for. For example, GCC on x86 will have 64-bit `long long`, and for amd64 it will have 64-bit `long` and `long long` types.

So:

```
long long digit = strtoll(input, NULL, 10);
```

NOTE: `strtoll()` is popular in Unix-like systems and became standard in C++11, but not all VC++ implementations have it. Use `_strtoi64()` instead:

```
__int64 digit = _strtoi64(input, NULL, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `atoll` function, which returns a `long long int`, that is twice as big as `int` (most likely 64 bits in your case).

It is declared in `stdlib.h`

http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoll

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid to call `atoi` on uninitialized string, if there is no `\0` on the string, you will invalid read and have a segmentation fault.
You should use `strtoimax` instead, it's more safe.

Answer (score 0):

9999999998 is bigger then the maximum value that an integer can represent. Either use `atol()` OR `atoll()`

Answer (score 0):

You should stop using `atoi` function or any other functions from `ato...` group. These functions are not officially deprecated, but they are effectively abandoned since 1995 and exist only for legacy code compatibility purposes. Forget about these functions as if they do not exist. These function provide no usable feedback in case of error or overflow. And overflow is what apparently happens in your example.

In order to convert strings to numbers, C standard library provides `strtol` function and other functions from `strto...` group. These are the functions you should use to perform the conversion. And don't forget to check the result for overflow: `strto...` functions provide this feedback through the return value and `errno` variable.